# Relationship hasMore on laravel getting twin results

Tags: php, laravel

I try to display data that has entered into **postlocation** to be displayed at each **location**, if the data is there then the color of the location will be green

[image: this is the result]

```
<div class="col-12 pl-0">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="location">Location</label>
        <br>
        <div>
            @foreach ($locations as $location)
                @foreach ($postlog->postlocationget as $postlocation)
                        @if($location->id == 1)
                        @else
                        <div style="cursor: pointer;" class="p-2 my-1 badge badge-pill @if($postlocation->location == $location->id) badge-success @else badge-info @endif" id="badgeloc{{$location->id}}">{{$location->location}} </div>
                        <input hidden="hidden" type="checkbox" id="checkloc{{$location->id}}">
                        @endif
                @endforeach                                                         
            @endforeach                                                         
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show us the `$locations` and `$postlog->postlocationget` in `json` format.

Comment: I have added the json data you requested